# Export to Excel using OpenXML and C#, Integers and DateTime

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, openxml

I'm writing an application that's supposed to export data from a map application.
This application is using Silverlight, and to facilitate export to Excel I am using [this](http://agopenxml.codeplex.com/) library.
All of the data is represented in strings by default. When I write to the spreadsheet, I try to parse each string to see which type it is:

```
string str = kvp.Value;
int i = 0;
long l = 0;
decimal dec = 0;
DateTime dt;
if (int.TryParse(str, out i))
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].SetValue(i);
else if (decimal.TryParse(str, out dec))
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].SetValue(dec);
else if (long.TryParse(str, out l))
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].SetValue(l);
else if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out dt))
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].SetValue(dt);
else
    doc.Workbook.Sheets[0].Sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].SetValue(str);
```

This works great, except for DateTime and when I try to parse a social security number, which in my case is 12 characters long.

The social security number is parsed as a decimal number, and is displayed in scientific form in Excel. From what I've gathered through reading it seems like a limitation in Excel. If I mark the cell however, I see the correct number in the top bar where you can write formulas. I've solved this problem so far by simply putting this number as a string and letting the end user handle it for now, but I'd really like for it to be a number in the finished document. Is this possible?

What really boggles my mind though, is the DateTime. The format of the date comes like this from the application: 10/15/2013 1:10:00 AM.
It looks like this in the Excel file: 2455075.

I checked the source code for the date formatting but I don't seem to be adept enough to see if there is anything wrong in it. For anyone intresed, you can check it out [here](http://agopenxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#FiftyNine.Ag.OpenXML.Excel/Elements/Cell.cs).

The SetValue-function is supposed to identify the following types automatically:

- bool
- DateTime
- decimal
- Exception
- SharedStringDefinition
- string

I apologize for the long post. It boils down to these questions:

- Can I make Excel handle long numbers without scientific notation programatically?
- Why is the DateTime being outputed to such a weird format?

Comment: Have you tried leaving everything as strings and seeing how they show up in Excel? Excel is usually pretty good at figuring out what type a column should be based on what the majority of values are.Also, to answer your DateTime question, this is the number of seconds since the first of January 1970.

Comment: @JMK When I add everything to the document as strings, it displays correctly and I don't get any scientific notations. However, coordinates and such is a hassle for end users to convert every time they want to export data, so I'm trying to make their lives a bit easier. Excel also notifies me that a field is actually a number but is displayed as a string. So it figures it out but it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: When you output as strings and check the format of the column when you open the actual Excel file, do they all say Text?

Comment: All fields get the type "General - no specific data type". I don't know if I translated it correctly, it is the top most selection in the drop down menu where you can change data type in Excel.

Comment: Well the fields that contain integers for example, can you do calculations with them? Because if you can and aren't getting a `Number stored as text` error you probably don't need to do anything!

Comment: @JMK Thank you, I ended up just handling numbers longer than 10 as strings. I cut down the decimals on coordinate values to still represent them as numbers in the excel document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be set Cell Value in Date format you have to convert DateTime to OLE Automation Date. Also you can create more clear method for writing cell values. Somthing like this:

```
public bool UpdateValue(WorkbookPart wbPart, string sheetName, string addressName, string value,
                            UInt32Value styleIndex, CellValues dataType)
    {
        // Assume failure.
        bool updated = false;

        Sheet sheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(
            (s) => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (sheet != null)
        {
            Worksheet ws = ((WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id))).Worksheet;
            Cell cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(ws, addressName);

            if (dataType == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                // Either retrieve the index of an existing string,
                // or insert the string into the shared string table
                // and get the index of the new item.
                int stringIndex = InsertSharedStringItem(wbPart, value);

                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(stringIndex.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
            }

            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataType);

            if (styleIndex > 0)
                cell.StyleIndex = styleIndex;

            // Save the worksheet.
            ws.Save();
            updated = true;
        }

        return updated;
    }
```

Then call this method like this (first call is for String second is for DateTime):

```
UpdateValue(workbookPart, wsName, "D14", "Some text", 0, CellValues.String);

UpdateValue(workbookPart, wsName, "H13", DateTime.Parse("2013-11-01").ToOADate().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 0, CellValues.Date);
```

Comment: I updated my solution with this. It works great and is a lot more elegant, thank you!